# If $x - \sqrt{ \frac{2}{x} } = 3 $ then $x-\sqrt{2x} = ?$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Please find the value without calculate the value of $x$. I tried to multipy it by $x$, I tried to square it but I still can't find the solution. I tried to make some equation that my help to solve this:
$$x^{2} + \frac{2}{x}-2\sqrt{2x} =9, $$

$$x^{2} - \sqrt{2x} = 3x,$$

$$x^2 - \frac{2}{x} = 3\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}\right).$$

Comment: Please write your question in such a way that we don't need to read the title to understand the body; the typography is set up that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&x - \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} = 3\\
&x\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2} = 3\sqrt{x}\\
&\sqrt{x}(x-3)=\sqrt{2}\\
&x(x-3)^2=2\\
&(x-2)(x^2-4x+1)=0
\end{align}

Note that $x=2$ is not a solution, so

$$x^2-4x+1=0 \implies x=2+\sqrt{3} \text{ or } x=2-\sqrt{3}$$

The second is not a solution either, so $x= 2+ \sqrt{3}.$

In that case, $x - \sqrt{2x} = 2+ \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2(2 + \sqrt{3})} = 2 + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{(\sqrt{3}+1)^2} = 1.$

Comment: Can it be done without finding $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt{\dfrac x2}=y\implies x=2y^2$

$$\implies2y^2-\dfrac1y=3\iff2y^3-3y-1=0$$

Let $x-\sqrt{2x}=2y^2-2y=2a,y^2-y-a=0\ \ \ \ (1)$

$2y-\dfrac1y=3-2a\iff2y^2+(2a-3)y-1=0\ \ \ \ (2)$

$(1),(2)$ will represent the same equation iff $$\dfrac12=\dfrac{-1}{2a-3}=\dfrac a1$$

Clearly $2a=?$